# Specialized explosives stats in WoD games

Tags: weapons, world-of-darkness

Like the title, I'm looking for stats of specialized explosives weaponry in oWoD games (any splat, since weapon stats are consistent across splats, and if there are no sources for that in oWoD sources, I will also accept answers based on CofD sources). I will also accept Storyteller's Vault sources if there are no official ones available. Preferred 20th Anniversary Editions (or equivalents) if possible, any other edition if not.

Specific weapons I need stats for are:

- **Flashbang Grenades** (having blindness and deafness times described would be a nice bonus),
- **Smoke Grenades** (numerical description of vision impairment is necessary),
- **Sting Grenades** (for those who don't know, those are crowd-control fragmentation grenades used by police, filled with rubber balls),
- **EMP Grenades** (having effects on technomagickal equipment described would be a nice bonus),
- **Incendiary Grenades**,
- Regular **infantry mines** and **vehicle mines**,
- Front-exhaust mines (**Claymore**).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### WoD Combat

WoD Combat, revised edition, pages 109/110 offers:

- M-79 Grenade Launcher
- Fragmentation Grenade
- Concussion Granade
- Smoke Grenade
- Tear Gas [Grenade]

### Hunter: The Reckoning

Hunter: the Reckoning, Revised edition, pages 207-208, is a subchapter on explosives. It contains from your list:

- Incendiary [Device] *Molotov cocktails*
- Concussion Grenades

### M20

Mage 20th-anniversary edition, pages 453-455 offers:

- M-79 & M-19 Grenade launchers
- Toxic Gas Grenade
- Concussion Grenade
- Fragmentation Grenad
- Molotov Cocktails
- IED
- Suicide Bomb
- Car Bomb
- Truck Bomb
- Napalm
- Small rocket
- Artillery shell
- Nuclear warhead. Yes. They exist. Their damage is **Seriously?** within 1-30 miles.

### The missing ones...

It's rather straightforward to get to most of the missing ones:

- Incendiary grenades could be treated either as Molotov Cocktails (HtR p.208 / M20 p.455), Incendiary Ammo (M20 p.454) or as a single person hit by Napalm (M20 p.455).
- Anti personnel-mines are roughly equivalent to something between a fragmentation grenade, an IED and a suicide bomb (M20 p.455)
- Vehicle mines are equivalent to an IED, Car, or Truck bomb. Or, for tank mines: Small rockets. (M20 p.455)
- Claymores are just anti-personnel mines. See above.
- Sting Grenades are a variant of the Fragmentation Grenade, so use those as the basis but apply bashing damage instead of lethal damage.

This leaves two. The more simple are EMP grenades... which simply are a Technomagical device in itself, using Forces+Correspondence to destroy electric devices. Or they are a Changeling's bunk for the Skycraft ** cantrip: Electric Gremlins (C20 p.219).

The harder case is modeling Flashbangs. Flashbangs are disorienting devices that don't do any or at least only little physical damage. To model such, of course, Technomagic comes into mind first: a Mind + Life effect could do that, reducing the dice pool of the target. But we can also just model with existing effects: M20 p.386 lists disorientation as one typical source of losing a few dice from the pool. On the other hand, M20 p.416 lists a blinded condition raising the difficulty by 2 for most rolls and preventing others. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stun_grenade) suggests that absolute blindness is about 5 seconds and afterimages for several times that, combined with (temporary) deafness. Combat turns are typically considered to be 3-5 seconds on average. That corresponds to 1-2 turns of total blindness, followed by about double that of heavy disorientation, maybe worth a number of dice that reduces by 1 each turn.

Comment: I'm surprised at the absence of flash-bang grenades. (As an aside, I've heard said that in any contemporary RPG, a player should look its rules for flash-bang grenades, martial arts, and shotguns because all 3 are almost inevitably overpowered; I was curious if that held true for flash-bangs in *WoD*.)

Comment: Hunter:The Reckoning has incendiary explosives (pg.208). Not worth my own answer, but a nice addition to yours.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, at least flashbangs aren't overpowered in Shadowrun, if only because anyone worth using them on will have cybernetics or goggles that make then immune. Martial arts are typically pretty strong, though.

Comment: @indigochild revised, yes? looking it up, adding!

Comment: @HeyICanChan I did manage to model them... but... they are *MEAN*. I mean, really.